# Looking for method argument validation framework based on AOP and annotations

Tags: java, validation, annotations, aop, arguments

I'm looking for argument validation framework which:
1) Allows specifying argument constraints via annontations (like OVal, JaValid)
2) Validation code automatically injected (during compilation or runtime) into methods (i.e. no explicit call to Validator object is required)

**Example of what i'm looking for:**

`public class Person {
    private String name;
    ....
    //Method which arguments should be validated
    public void setName(@NotBlank String name){
        //<---validating code should be injected here
        this.name = name;
    }
}` 


`//Example of call to the validated method
...
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("John");
...`

**Example of code i'm trying to avoid**

`...
    Validator validator = new Validator(...);//glue code
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("John");
    validator.validate(person);//glue code
...`

Thanks for answers!

Comment: I've found an appropriate solution (btw it was in OVal docs), - it's possible to integrate OVal with Spring AOP, for example by using DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator. It's still not perfect solution (since it requires use of spring, and OVal constraints are't type specific like i wanted).

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant "automatically injected during compilation or runtime", right?

I had the same problem. My solution was Spring Validation and self-written AOP layer (about three classes).

My validation code looks like this:

> @Validational( validators =
> {"com.mycompany.MyValidator"} )
>
> public void myMethod( String paramToValidate )

Comment: Thanks for hint - corrected this part in question. Self-written AOP layer is most obvious solution, i'd similar idea (OVal+Javassist), but i still hope there is ready-made solution to avoid unnecessary coding.